# How to simulate a state transition matrix?

Tags: r

Suppose I want to simulate a 5 by 5 state transition matrix i.e. if i and j are the state then i=j=0(1)5. For given "i" I want to generate random sample (j) of size 10 (the eventual number of transitions constituting will become N=50) using the relation given in below

```
j=ln(1-U) -1; i=0
j=ln(1-U)+i-2;  i>=1
```

where U ~ uniform(0,1).

I tried to write my R code as:

```
 nchain <- 100 ## no of simulation##

 i <- 0:4

 U <- runif(50,0,1)

 j <- rep(0,nchain)

 for(k in 1:nchain){
  if (i=0) {
      j=log(1-U)-1
  } else {
    j=log(1-U)+i-2
  }
}
```

But I couldn't able to do.
How to simulate 100 such type of matrices?

Comment: Please format your R code properly so that it’s readable (this means indentation, proper spacing around operators etc).

Comment: `i=j=0(1)5` doesn't really make sense. Is that supposed to be a concise way of specifying a 5x5 state transition matrix? If so, it isn't very clear. Please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: Here i and j are the states that means there are 5 states and it is 5 by 5 matrix.

Comment: Your code contains no matrix. Please give a sample matrix and explain what this matrix is supposed to represent. Also, if the states are supposed to be integers as in a discrete Markov chain, how does it make sense to use logarithms to initialize them?

Comment: Suppose there is a 2 by 2 matrix. Then the entries are n_{11}, n_{12}, n_{21} and n_{22}. Here n_{ij} denotes that the number of transition from state i to state j. So this is a positive integer. In the above problem it is a 5 by 5 matrix and the row sum is 10 .

Comment: You could edit your question so that it contains an actual matrix, as well as a description of what you are trying to do. It is not at all clear how your attempt to simulate individual exponentially distributed random variables is at all related to "simulating state transition matrices". Your code seems unrelated to your question and your question lacks detail.